Binary to base64 in SQL Server Compact edition
I have a SQL Server Compact edition database. I try to export binary data, but I see System.Byte[] instead of value.
I want to convert binary to base64 for export, but base64_encode doesn't work.
I open db with "Database .net v4 plus". Can you show me some way to export binary data to base64?

@Charlieface SQL Compact does not have FOR XML

Use Sqlite Toolbox  - it has an option to show binary values

@ErikEJ Didn't know that. Considering the last edition was released in 2011 and the latest SP is only supported to 2025, not surprised. Might be time to move on.
